# Understanding the Glivenko-Cantelli lemma in relation to strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

Consider the following estimator of the distribution function $F$. Let a sequence of a random variables $X_i$ be i.i.d with distribution function $F$ and our estimator $\hat{F}_n(X) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(X_i \leq x)$ and $I$ is an indicator function.

Now the strong law of large numbers states for a fixed $x$ that $\hat{F}_n(X) \rightarrow_{as} F(X)$.

The Glivenko Gantelli theorem states that $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |\hat{F}_n(x) - F(x)| \rightarrow_{as} 0$.

What I'm failing to understand is why the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem doesn't follow from the strong law of large numbers? If we show convergence for each individual $x$ wouldn't that imply convergence of the supremum? Can someone provide a counter example if this is not the case?

Answer (score 1):

The law of large numbers says that for each $x$ you have a null set $N_x$ such that for all $\omega \in N^c$ $\hat F_n(x)(\omega) \to F(x)$.

Now for the convergence of the supremum you'd have to look at the union of all $N_x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. This could be a non-null set (as the union is over an uncountable index set), thus the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem is a strict improvement over the law of large number!

Comment: Even  if you can put all the null sets inside  a single null set uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$ is a stronger statement and surely requires a proof.

Comment: @KaboMurphy you are completely right, even for deterministic functions pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence.

Comment: Sorry i'm not familiar with a lot of the maths behind your answer, is there anyway to give a layman explanation? One thing i perhaps may have understood is that the type of convergence is more specific in the lemma than the SLLN. As a separate note what area of maths looks into these issues from a technical level? My guess is something like measure theory and analysis? This is so i can begin to look into the technical stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PavanSangha Yes, measure theory and probability theory are the topics you might want to read up on. But the other point made can be understood without any probability theory: Pointwise convergence (the statement of the SLLN) does not imply uniform convergence (the statement of Glivenko-Cantelli theorem) even in a deterministic setting. Consider $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ with $f_n(x) = x^n$. Then $f_n \to_{pw} \delta_{\{1\}}$ but $\lVert f_n - \delta_{\{1\}} \rVert_\infty = 1$ and does not go to $0$!

Comment: Thanks for the concrete example what is $\delta_{\{1\}}$? and we are assuming $n \rightarrow \infty$ in $f_n(x)=x^n$? I think i get the idea though, convergence can be different across the function, so by looking at the specific value of supremum we are saying something much more specific.

Comment: The function that is $1$ for $x = 1$ and $0$ for other $x$.